# Why does onClick cause a loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement Minesweeper in React and whenever the player clicks on a mine, the board is reset and re-rendered, but the cell that the player initially clicked containing the mine appears to fire onClick again after the board resets.
I've noticed additionally that if I don't reset the board after hitting a mine, but instead call alert() and then return without changing state, then game loops until a stack overflow occurs.

This is how my stateful board component looks when I display an alert after game over and do not change state:

```jsx
render() {
  let squareGrid = this.state.currentGrid.slice();
  return (
    squareGrid.map((row, y) => { //For each row
        return ( //Create a division
          <div key={y}>
            {
              row.map((state, x) => {//Render a square for each index
                let value = (state.touched) ? state.minedNeighbors :"_";
                return <Square mine={squareGrid[y][x].mine} key={x} disabled={state.touched} val={value}
                  onClick={() => this.handleClick(y, x)}> </Square>

              })}
          </div>
        )
      }
    )
  )
}

handleClick(row, column) {
  // Get copy of grid
  const grid = this.state.currentGrid.slice();
  //If the player clicks a mine, game over.
  if (grid[row][column].mine) {
    //this.resetGame(); //This function does cause a state change

    alert("You have died.");
    return;
  }

  //Non-pure function that mutates grid
  this.revealNeighbors(row, column, grid);

  this.setState({
    currentGrid: grid
  })
}
```

My Square component is a function

```
function Square(props) {
    return (
        <button className={"gameButton"} disabled={props.disabled} onClick={props.onClick}>
            {props.val}
        </button>
    );
}
```

The code, as is, will repeatedly display an alert over and over again once the player clicks a mine.
If I uncomment the line in handleClick that resets the game, the board will be correctly reset, but the cell that the player last clicked will be revealed as if the player had clicked it again after the board reset.

A lot of the other posts that have had my issue are due to the onClick attribute containing a function call instead of a function pointer, but as far as I can tell, I'm not calling the function directly in render; I'm providing a closure.

Edit:
Here is the full code for my Board component.

```
class Board extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        let grid = this.createGrid(_size);

        this.state = {
            size: _size,
            currentGrid: grid,
            reset: false
        }
    }

    createGrid(size) {
        const grid = Array(size).fill(null);
        //Fill grid with cell objects
        for (let row = 0; row < size; row++) {
            grid[row] = Array(size).fill(null);
            for (let column = 0; column < size; column++) {
                grid[row][column] = {touched: false, mine: Math.random() < 0.2}
            }
        }

        //Reiterate to determine how many mineNeighbors each cell has
        for (let r = 0; r < size; r++) {
            for (let c = 0; c < size; c++) {
                grid[r][c].minedNeighbors = this.countMineNeighbors(r, c, grid)
            }
        }

        return grid;
    }

    handleClick(row, column) {
        const grid = this.state.currentGrid.slice();

        //If the player clicks a mine, game over.
        if (grid[row][column].mine) {
            //this.resetGame();
            //grid[row][column].touched = true;
            alert("You have died.");
            return;
        }

        //Non-pure function that mutates grid
        this.revealNeighbors(row, column, grid);

        this.setState({
            currentGrid: grid
        })
    }

    //Ensure cell is in bounds
    checkBoundary(row, column) {
        return ([row, column].every(x => 0 <= x && x < this.state.size));
    }


    revealNeighbors(row, column, grid) {
        //Return if out of bounds or already touched
        if (!this.checkBoundary(row, column) || grid[row][column].touched) {
            return;
        }

        //Touch cell
        grid[row][column].touched = true;

        if (grid[row][column].minedNeighbors === 0) {
            //For each possible neighbor, recurse.
            [[1, 0], [-1, 0], [0, 1], [0, -1]]
                .forEach(pos => this.revealNeighbors(row + pos[0], column + pos[1], grid));
        }

    }


    countMineNeighbors(row, column, grid) {
        let size = grid.length;

        //Returns a coordinate pair representing the position of the cell in the direction of the angle, eg, Pi/4 radians -> [1,1]
        let angleToCell = (angle) => [Math.sin, Math.cos]
            .map(func => Math.round(func(angle)))
            .map((val, ind) => val + [row, column][ind]);

        return Array(8)
            .fill(0)
            .map((_, ind) => ind * Math.PI / 4) //Populate array with angles toward each neighbor
            .map(angleToCell)
            .filter(pos => pos.every(x => 0 <= x && x < size))//Remove out of bounds cells
            .filter(pos => grid[pos[0]][pos[1]].mine)//Remove cells that aren't mines
            .length //Return the length of the array as the count
    }

    resetGame() {
        this.setState({
                currentGrid: this.createGrid(this.state.size)
            }
        )
    }

    render() {
        let squareGrid = this.state.currentGrid.slice();
        return (
            squareGrid.map((row, y) => { //For each rows
                    return ( //Create a division
                        <div key={y}>
                            {
                                row.map((state, x) => {//Render a square for each index
                                    let value = (state.touched) ? state.minedNeighbors : "_";
                                    return <Square mine={squareGrid[y][x].mine} key={x} disabled={state.touched} val={value}
                                                   onClick={() => this.handleClick(y, x)}/>

                                })}
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any warnings or errors in the console output?

Comment: Whats happening in this `this.revealNeighbors`?

Comment: Can you provide an interactive example (i.e. jsfiddle) or at least full component code?

Comment: There are no errors that I've seen, other than the infinite loop.

Comment: @BrianThompson The local grid provided to it is recursively searched and all cells that have no mine neighbors are touched. It doesn't change the global state and it returns the modified local grid. I have provided the code for it.

Comment: @GennadyDogaev Sorry, I couldn't get a working jsfiddle, but I have provided the full code for the Board component.

Comment: Idk, everything seems to work fine in sandbox - no repeated alert, reset also works fine https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-volhard-7ogge

Comment: This looks like a minimum reproducible example would be welcome, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . Such minimal “reprex” would help readers (the people that might help you). Also, my experience shows that creating minimal reprex can help to identify some important details of the problem. Sometimes, just creating the reprex can lead to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

All the time when you change your state your render method is called.

```
this.setState({
        currentGrid: grid
    })
```

probably you should implement a method called shouldComponentUpdate to prevent this to happen. Also, your slice is not being resolved. I'd suggest you to try with async/await.

Comment: I see, but because this.resetGame() is commented out, the state is not changed when the player clicks a mine, and because the function returns afterwards, I don't see why it would re-render or why onClick would be invoked again.

Comment: Because your code  const grid = this.state.currentGrid.slice(); is not resolved in time. So async handleClick(...  = await this.state.currentGrid.slice(); and see what happens.

Comment: I tried that, but got the same results; infinite alerts.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a problem like this if you click on a element that becomes rerendered. I'm not sure if this will solve the problem in your particular situation but I've found 2 solutions that have worked for me in the past.

One is to put a flag in your mouse click event,

```
if(!mouseDownFlag){
mouseDownFlag = true;
//the rest of your onetime code
}
```

and then have the flag removed on the mouseupevent

Alternatively, sometimes using the mousedown event instead of mouseclick, can be more predictable.

Hopefully one of these solutions help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the way you pass and use the click function (when passing a function as a prop you only want to pass a reference to the function not call it, hence excluding the `()`)

```
 return 
     <Square 
         mine={squareGrid[y][x].mine} 
         key={x} disabled={state.touched} 
         val={value}
         // **** change line below
         onClick={this.handleClick}
     > </Square>
```

And when you call it

```
 <button 
     className={"gameButton"} 
     disabled={props.disabled} 
     // **** change line below
     onClick={() => props.onClick()}>
         {props.val}
</button>
```

Comment: It looks like they're declaring an inline function, not executing it. The prop looks correct.

Comment: In my render function I'm not invoking the function, I'm passing in an arrow function containing the function. It already looks the way you've written it, if I'm not mistaken. Also, if I call it without using a closure I'll lose the arguments.

Comment: @Tayler Cooper, From what I see you have it the opposite of what it should be, you are passing it with parenthesis and calling it without parenthesis. in my answer I just swapped them to be in the right order (In the `<Square>` you are passing it and in the `<button>` you are calling the function), that's what I understood, though I might be wrong.